# Como trocar uma palavra entre um limite criado por dois pontos específicos dentro de uma string?

Tags: python-3.x

Entre a palavra `fogo` e a palavra `gelo` existe um conteúdo, e o objetivo é mudar esse conteúdo por `sobrenatural`

código:

```
s = "1 fogo bom dia gelo 2 fogo boa tarde gelo 3 fogo boa noite gelo 4"

s = s.replace('\n\n','\t')
start = 'fogo'
end = 'gelo'

for i in range(len(s)): #1 fogo sobrenatural gelo 2 fogo sobrenatural gelo 3 fogo sobrenatural gelo 4
  if s[i:i+len(start)] == start:
    for j in range(i+len(start), len(s)):
      if s[j:j+len(end)] == end:
        g = s[i + len(start):j]
        v=s.replace(g,' sobrenatural ')
        print(v)
        break
```

O print como está saindo:

```
1 fogo sobrenatural gelo 2 fogo boa tarde gelo 3 fogo boa noite gelo 4
1 fogo bom dia gelo 2 fogo sobrenatural gelo 3 fogo boa noite gelo 4
1 fogo bom dia gelo 2 fogo boa tarde gelo 3 fogo sobrenatural gelo 4
```

O print correto seria:

```
1 fogo sobrenatural gelo 2 fogo sobrenatural gelo 3 fogo sobrenatural gelo 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit:
> Conforme lembrado nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/506492/como-trocar-uma-palavra-entre-um-limite-criado-por-dois-pontos-espec%C3%ADficos-dentr/506522#comment933158_506522) pelo usuário [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) foi adicionado o padrão `\b` que corresponde a string vazia, apensado ao inicio e ao final de padrão determinando um limite formal da palavra a ser correspondida assim evitando a captura de *"Botafogo .... gelol"*, *"fogos ... congelou"*,...

Ao invés de vasculhar uma string, em um conjunto de laços, caractere por caractere buscando as strings delimitadores para então fazer a substituição em uma atividade propensa a erros. Substitua um conjunto de caracteres delimitados por duas palavras específicas utilizando [expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), que em Python são usada através do [módulo re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

No seu caso específico, uma string delimitada pelas palavras `fogo` e `gelo`, pode ser feita com o padrão de correspondência `(?<=\bfogo\b).+?(?=\bgelo\b)`, onde:

- `(?<=\bfogo\b)`: padrão de correspondência *lookbehind*. Faz a correspondência apenas se a string for precedida pela string `fogo`.
- `.+?` :  corresponde a um ou mais caracteres quaisquer de forma não gananciosa, ou seja fará a menor correspondência possível.
- `(?=\bgelo\b)`: padrão de correspondência *lookahead*. Faz a correspondência apenas se a string for seguida pela string `gelo`.

Para fazer a substituição pode ser usado o método [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.sub). No caso o exemplo utilizou a flag [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) que faz a correspondência não diferenciando maiúsculas de minúsculas:

```
import re

s = "1 fogo bom dia gelo 2 fogo boa tarde gelo 3 fogo boa noite gelo 4"

p = r'(?<=\bfogo\b).+?(?=\bgelo\b)'                       #Determina o padrão de captura.

r = re.sub(p, " sobrenatural ", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)  #Faz capturas e substituições.

print(r)                                                 
# 1 fogo sobrenatural gelo 2 fogo sobrenatural gelo 3 fogo sobrenatural gelo 4
```

<sup>Teste no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/SlateblueCriminalScan#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Eu só acrescentaria o `\b` para evitar casos como "Botafogo etc gelol", "fogos etc congelou", etc - não ficou claro se é pra tratar esses casos, mas enfim...